# Moving or copying several files at once in Powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

In bash, you can

```
cp filea fileb filec Folder
```

which will copy `filea` `fileb` and `filec` into `Folder`

For some reason, i couldn't find a way to do the same thing in Powershell. 
Everywhere i looked, all i could find is just the possibility to use wildcards in order to move 
a bunch of files from the same type like:

```
cp *.txt Folder
```

But that's not what i'm looking for. I'm looking for a way to copy several files 
by their names in one command.

Does anybody knows a way to do that?

Answer (score 2):

**"I'm looking for a way to copy several files
by their names in one command."**

Here are three examples that can do what you want. The first one is closest to what you're looking for.

```bsh
param(
    $files = @('filea', 'fileb', 'filec'),
    $dest = 'Folder'
)

Copy-Item -LiteralPath $files -Destination $dest -Verbose

$files | ForEach-Object { Copy-Item -Path $_ -Destination $dest -Verbose }

foreach ($file in $files) { Copy-Item -Path $file -Destination $dest -Verbose }
```

Comment: while the code is neatly done, four prep lines makes that a rather loose definition of "one liner" ... [*grin*]

Comment: @Lee_Dailey, I was kind of thinking the same. Edited as per that thought.

Comment: neat! thanks for removing that bit of confusion ... [*grin*]

Answer (score 0):

A one liner to do:

```
@("file1","file2","filen") | % {Copy -Path $_ -Destination "destination"}
```